# checkbox knockout click binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know that knockout expects us to return `true` in the function bound to `click` event in order to check/uncheck a checkbox.

I tried the following [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ock4jry6/27/) but it is not checking the check boxes. I can display the value using an anonymous computed function but my array can be huge and I don't want to keep performance overhead.

Is there any other way of doing it? or Am I doing it wrong?

**Edit**: Adding the code

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: array">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.child">  
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, click: function(data, event){$parentContext.$parent.clickBox(data, event, $parent)}">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.value"></span>    
    </div>
   <p data-bind="text: label"></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var mainModel = function(){
  var self = this;  
  self.isChecked = ko.observable(true);  
  self.clickBox = function(data, event, $parent){
    var j=0;
    for(var i=0; i<$parent.length; i++){
        if($parent[i].isChecked()){
        j++;
      }
    }
    $parent.label(j);
    return true;
  }

  self.array = ko.observable(
  [
    {child: [
        {value: 'a', isChecked: ko.observable(false)},
      {value: 'b', isChecked: ko.observable(false)}],
     label: ko.observable(0)
    },
    {child: [
        {value: 'c', isChecked: ko.observable(false)},
      {value: 'd', isChecked: ko.observable(false)}],
     label: ko.observable(0)
    }
  ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new mainModel());
```

Comment: Fiddle is acceptable on top of code shown here, not as a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `return`, change following code

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, 
click:   function(data, event){
$parentContext.$parent.clickBox(data, event, $parent)}">
```

To

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, 
click:   function(data, event){
return $parentContext.$parent.clickBox(data, event, $parent)}">
```

if you don't pass return handler, by default knockout will prevent the action by calling

```
 if (handlerReturnValue !== true) { 
       if (event.preventDefault)
             event.preventDefault();
        else
             event.returnValue = false;
    }
```